# Crear for en JavaScript de varios inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

estoy extrayendo información de unos inputs con JavaScript y ahora quiero hacer un arreglo con ellos para pasarlo al controlador con AJAX y guardarlos en bd.

**El HTML generado por JavaScritp**

```
$("#respuesta").val(data.producto.id);/*Esto es para traer el ID del producto, para poder modificarlo*/
                        var boton = '<a class="btn btnGuardar guardaVariaciones" id="guardaCombinaciones" data-id="">Guardar combinaciones</a>';

                    for (var i = 0; i < data.permutaciones.length; i++) {
                        var id = data.permutaciones[i].id;
                        var productoid = data.permutaciones[i].product_id;
                        var combinacion = data.permutaciones[i].combination;
                        var precio = data.permutaciones[i].precio;
                        var oferta = data.permutaciones[i].oferta;

                        var a = `<div id="accordion${id}">
                            <div class="cardCollapse">
                                <button class="btn btn-link collapsed btnCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse${id}" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse${id}">
                                    <div class="card-header" id="heading${id}">
                                        <h5 class="mb-0">      
                                            Producto <span style="color: #427ff2;top: 0px;font-weight: 700!important;">#${productoid}</span>
                                        </h5>
                                        <span class="pull-right spanCollapse">${combinacion}</span>
                                    </div>
                                </button>
                          
                              <div id="collapse${id}" class="collapse fondoCollapse" aria-labelledby="heading${id}" data-parent="#accordion${id}">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <div class="row rowDotted">
                                        <div class="col-6">
                                            <div class="eFoto">    
                                                <span style="position: relative">
                                                    <img id="holder${id}" src="{{ asset('images/no-foto.jpg') }}" alt="" class="imgEditPerf334">
                                                    <a data-input="thumbnail${id}" data-preview="holder${id}" class="lfm">
                                                        <i class="fas fa-pen editaFotoProducto334"></i>
                                                    </a>  
                                                </span>
                                                <input id="thumbnail${id}" class="form-control formNuevo pemutasBuena" type="hidden" name="imagen" value="" required>   
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-6">
                                            <div class="form-group" style="position:relative;">
                                                <label for="">Referencia</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control myinputs pemutasBuena" name="refeJava" id="refeJava" value="" autocomplete="off" required>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-6">
                                            <div class="form-group" style="position:relative;">
                                                <span class="simboloMedida556">€</span>
                                                <label for="">Precio normal</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control myinputs pemutasBuena" name="precio" id="precio" value="${precio}" autocomplete="off" required>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-6">
                                            <div class="form-group" style="position:relative;">
                                                <span class="simboloMedida556">€</span>
                                                <label for="">Precio ofertado</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control myinputs pemutasBuena" name="oferta" id="oferta" value="${oferta}" autocomplete="off" required>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>`;
                        $("#permutas").append(a);
                    }
                    $("#permutas").append(boton);

$( "#guardaCombinaciones" ).click(function() {
      var valores = [];                 
      var imagen = $(".fotoProdu").val();
      var referencia = $(".refeJava").val();
      var precio = $(".precio").val();
      ar oferta = $(".oferta").val();
                        
      valores.push(imagen, referencia, precio, oferta);

      console.log(valores);
});
```

De cada fila siempre guardara estos 4 inputs, pero puede ser que alguno no sea rellenado y es posible. Estoy intentando de la forma de arriba, y creo que lo saco bien.

```
(4) ["/photos/shares/Productos/Sudadera-con-capucha-sweit-eme-delante-600x600.jpg", "P5353343", "20", "15"]
0: "/photos/shares/Productos/Sudadera-con-capucha-sweit-eme-delante-600x600.jpg"
1: "P5353343"
2: "20"
3: "15"
length: 4
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Los numero me gustaria ponerle un nombre por ejemplo 'Imagen' = valor.
Por cada linea con sus 4 elementos tiene que separar el arreglo, no se si me explico.

He intentado hacer un for pero no soy muy experto en esto la verdad.

Bien estoy probando de la siguiente manera, y me trae los datos que necesito, pero todos juntos claro, necesito que por cada fila sea un arreglo.

Lo hago así:

```
$( "#guardaCombinaciones" ).click(function() {
    let posis = $('.pemutasBuena');
    let arrIds = [];
      posis.each(function(index) {
      arrIds[index] = {
         id: $(this).attr('id'),
         combinacion: $(this).val() || []
      };
     })
    console.log(arrIds);
});
```

Obtengo esto:

```
0: {id: "thumbnail286", combinacion: "/photos/shares/1.jpg"}
1: {id: "refeJava", combinacion: "REF1902"}
2: {id: "precio", combinacion: "20"}
3: {id: "oferta", combinacion: "10"}
4: {id: "thumbnail287", combinacion: "/photos/shares/Productos/Sudadera-con-capucha-sweit-eme-delante-600x600.jpg"}
5: {id: "refeJava", combinacion: "REF103"}
6: {id: "precio", combinacion: "20"}
7: {id: "oferta", combinacion: Array(0)}
length: 8
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Comment: Pensaba que lo habia puesto, saco bien la primera fila, pero si hay más de una solo sale la primera, por eso supongo que necesito hacer un `for` y es lo que no me sale

Comment: Sin ver el html al que hace referencia es imposible saber cómo podemos sacar nada de él. Actualiza la pregunta añadendo el html, por favor.

Comment: Es una cadena HTML generada por JavaScript, por eso no la puse. Pensaba que obteniendo los valores que necesito podria construir un arreglo @Benito-B

Comment: `$("#refeJava").val();` Esto solo va a encontrar el primer elemento con id 'refeJava'. Además, no se debería tener elementos con id repetidas. Te sugiero que uses una clase en vez del elemento y que uses foreach al buscarlas para recorrer todas las que encuentra. Si quieres usar "nombres" en vez de números, utiliza un JSON o un array de objetos javascript y así puedes hacer `valores[0].nombre ="blabla"`

Comment: Por eso necesito hacer un for no? lo de la ID es lo de menos, puedo hacer que coja las clases en lugar de la ID

Comment: Como usas jQuery, te recomiendo que leas cómo funciona el [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

Comment: Eso a lo que haces referencia @Benito-B `Si quieres usar "nombres" en vez de números, utiliza un JSON o un array ` es lo que estoy solicitando en la pregunta al igual que lo de `uses foreach`. Ya lo he cambiado por clases

Comment: Hola @Benito-B modifique la respuesta añadiendo el html que me genera el JavaScript y además añado una forma en la que estoy probando

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De lo que te entiendo los inputs son generados por un javascript es decir que no sabemos cuantos se van a generar. Al agregar una clase única a input puedes acceder a los datos que necesitas y posterior mente formar el objeto que necesitas.

Supongamos que en este caso solo tenemos 2 items con 2 inputs.

```js
$("#values").click(() => {
  let x1 = $(".test1");
  let x2 = $(".test2");
    
  let y = [];
  
  for(var i=0; i < x1.length; i++){
    y.push([["prop1", x1[i].value],["prop2", x2[i].value]]);
 
  }
  
  console.log(y);
  
  let z = y.map(aux => Object.fromEntries(aux));
  
  console.log(z);
  
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="test1">
<input type="text" class="test2">
<br/>
<input type="text" class="test1">
<input type="text" class="test2">
<br/>
<button id="values">Get Values</button>
```

como puedes ver en **x1, x2** se guardan los inputs, posteriormente recorremos uno de las 2 variables pues deben tener siempre el mismo tamaño. De esta forma tomamos los valores y los juntamos como un par de valores para posteriormente usar **fromEntries**. Mapeamos el array y lo convertimos a un objeto con cada propiedad que guardamos.

Espero te sirva, mas info de [fromEntries](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/fromEntries)

Comment: Creo que no es lo que necesito, quizas no sepa explicarme ya que no entiendo bien lo que hago @DavElsanto , no se si existe la posibilidad de ir al chat?

Comment: revisa bien lo que te publiqué, yo la verdad si creo que responde a tus necesidades simplemente debes cambiar los textos en el **push** de la variable **y**. Donde en lugar de **prop1** solo cambiala a **id**, a **prop2** cambiala **nombre**, etc.

Comment: Si te iba a escribir ahora, es correcto todo lo que pones, muchas gracias @DavElsanto

Comment: Perdona @DavElsanto , y si quiero traer el valor de un html??

Comment: Depende si ya está renderizado o no.

Comment: No se si está renderizado, no lo entiendo. De las otras formas que probaba me lo traia así `$(".combinacionPermuta").html();` pero ahora no funciona por que supongo  que esto de abajo `["prop4", x4[i].value]` al poner value no funciona

Comment: si no hay problema, lo que entiendo es que quieres guardar el html como texto, lo que te aconsejo es reemplaces tolas las comillas dobles por comillas simples para que no tengas problemas al guardarlo como objeto dado que no va a tener el formato correcto ej **"prop4", "<div class="aaa"></div>"** la clase debe tener la siguiente forma **class='aaa'**. https://dmitripavlutin.com/replace-all-string-occurrences-javascript/

Comment: Lo que quiero sacar en HTML, lo tengo en dos variables de JavaSript, es posible mejor así?, he cambiado las comillas ya, @DavElsanto